# Counting Pattern Per Column From Line X to Y Using AWK

Tags: awk, bioinformatics

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Sample_ID Population CP026243.1_309     CP026243.1_318  CP026243.1_427  CP026243.1_449  CP026243.1_515
Turbot-BalticSea_01     BalticSea       0       0       0
Turbot-BalticSea_02     BalticSea       -1      -1      -1
Turbot-BalticSea_03     BalticSea       -1      -1      0
Turbot-BalticSea_04     BalticSea       0       0       -1
Turbot-BalticSea_05     BalticSea       -1      -1      0
Turbot-BalticSea_06     BalticSea       -1      0       0
Turbot-BalticSea_07     BalticSea       -1      -1      -1
Turbot-BalticSea_08     BalticSea       0       0       0
Turbot-BalticSea_09     BalticSea       0       0       1
Turbot-BalticSea_10     BalticSea       0       0       0
Turbot-BalticSea_11     BalticSea       -1      -1      1
Turbot-BalticSea_12     BalticSea       0       0       0
Turbot-BalticSea_13     BalticSea       0       0       0
Turbot-BalticSea_14     BalticSea       0       1       -1
Turbot-BalticSea_15     BalticSea       0       0       0
Turbot-BalticSea_16     BalticSea       0       0       0
Turbot-BalticSea_17     BalticSea       0       0       -1
Turbot-Kattegat_01      Kattegat        0       -1      0
Turbot-Kattegat_02      Kattegat        -1      -1      0
Turbot-Kattegat_03      Kattegat        -1      -1      -1
Turbot-Kattegat_04      Kattegat        0       0       0
Turbot-Kattegat_05      Kattegat        -1      -1      -1
Turbot-Kattegat_06      Kattegat        -1      -1      -1
```

I would like to know how I could count the number of "-1" in each column (starting from the 3rd column and from the second row) per population (BalticSea / Kattegat).

I guess AWK would be good for doing this?

```
cat TEMP.tsv | awk 'NR>1{...}'
```

Thanks a lot in advance, George.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk you could do something like this:

```
tail -n +2 TEMP.tsv | awk '$3=="-1" { count[$2]++ } END {for (word in count) print word, count[word]}'
```

which counts the occurrences of -1 in the 3rd column grouped by 2nd column value.

Note that tail command removes the header.

$3 in the awk command is checking for third column. Use $4, $5 for the fourth, fifth column and so on..

To do it for all the columns using a single awk script create a file for example grpbycount.awk:

```
BEGIN {}
{
  for ( counter = 3; counter <=NF; counter++ ) {
   if ($counter=="-1") count[counter","$2]++
  }
}
END {
  for ( word in count) print word, count[word]
}
```

Then use this command:

```
tail -n +2 TEMP.tsv | awk -f grpbycount.awk | sort
```

For your input, this results in the count as below

```
3,BalticSea 6
3,Kattegat 4
4,BalticSea 5
4,Kattegat 5
5,BalticSea 5
5,Kattegat 3
```

First numeric value is the column number followed by the value from column 2, and then it prints the count.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Would that be possible to do that for all the columns at once? I actually have millions of columns. So I guess I would need some sort of loop and would go over each column.

Comment: @GeorgePacheco see my edit above on how to achieve this for all columns at once.